# Barcode scanner work in browser

Tags: windows-7, browser, barcode-scanner

I have a Manhattan Barcode scanner Contact CCD Handheld 80mm scan width, USB. I have connected it to Windows 7 x64.

I managed to get it to scan several barcodes by configuring it to USB Mode.
If I open up Notepad it scans and displays the barcodes correctly.

But when I set the cursor in a textbox in my browser (IE9 beta, Firefox 3.6 or Chrome 8.0 beta), it scans correctly but opens the download dialog afterwards.

This gets triggered by CTRL+J normally....

What did I do wrong? I tried several barcodes (Code128 and several others) and tried different browsers and Notepad. it works in Notepad but doesn't in the browsers...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had to set the terminator to CR instead of CR+LF which was the default

Comment: How can I do this?

Comment: I found it in the manual of the scanner. Had to configure the scanner by scanning some special barcodes in the manual to configure it.

Comment: Thank you very much! I found the special barcode from the internet! :)

Answer (score 1):

I set terminator to None and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using Chrome try this extension
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/search/shortcuts%20for%20chrome

just change the shortcut for Ctrl+ j

Works for me